# angularstrap typeahead return [Object object] instead of json object with latest angular version v.1.3.13

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead, angular-strap

It works fine with angular v-1.3.beta-7 but when I moved to latest version of angular controller.$viewValue return [Object object] instead of {key:value} pair json.

Comment: How are you accessing `controller.$viewValue`? It seems like you are converting it to a string somehow, which is why you are getting `[Object object]`.

Comment: Consider posting your code, as I am also using type ahead with 1.3 version and for me it works fine

Comment: i'hv found the cure, actually older version of typeahead doesn't supported with angular v.1.3.13 as previous angular version return the controller.$viewValue in format which we have supplied to it but v.1.3.13 and above returns controller.$viewValue in string only. This issue fixed in latest angular strap typeahead.